# Change perspective script to orthographic unity 2d

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d, game-development

I am trying to change this script that I found online https://pressstart.vip/tutorials/2018/09/25/58/spawning-obstacles.html to work with a orthographic camera because that is what my game uses. At the moment it only works with perspective cameras and I don't really know how this works cause I have not really touched the camera matrix. Here is the code for the script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class deployAsteroids : MonoBehaviour {
    public GameObject asteroidPrefab;
    public float respawnTime = 1.0f;
    private Vector2 screenBounds;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        screenBounds = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(Screen.width, Screen.height, Camera.main.transform.position.z));
        StartCoroutine(asteroidWave());
    }
    private void spawnEnemy(){
        GameObject a = Instantiate(asteroidPrefab) as GameObject;
        a.transform.position = new Vector2(screenBounds.x * -2, Random.Range(-screenBounds.y, screenBounds.y));
    }
    IEnumerator asteroidWave(){
        while(true){
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(respawnTime);
            spawnEnemy();
        }
    }
}
```

My goal is to change the script to make it work correctly with a orthographic camera. (The indentation is messed up and that is not the problem).

Comment: What does it do that's different than your intended goal? Does it crash your computer? Spawn things on the wrong side of the screen? There is no way for us to know.  Also, please cite the source for your code, or you are committing plagiarism.

Comment: obstacle spawns off the screen and instantly gets destroyed.

Comment: Just use `screenBounds = Camera.main.ViewportToWorldPoint(new Vector3(0f, 0f, -Camera.main.transform.position.z));` and it should work in perspective and ortho cameras. Be sure to change the same line that occurs in the `asteroid` class. Code is pretty sloppy, I would avoid that source in the future.

Comment: I am now trying to make the object come down vertically but all the changes I make i can not get it it change

Comment: ..top to bottom

Comment: Also your fix works

Comment: Glad to hear it. If my answer helped, please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/405359). Changing the asteroids' travel to be vertical sounds like [a different problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43478/405359). Consider [asking a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) and showing your research, including what you have tried to achieve it.

Comment: ok thanks for your help anyway sorry for asking other questions

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243306/discussion-between-gcireland-and-ruzihm).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason the code is using `Camera.main.transform.position.z` for the camera depth component. This value will be negative in a typical camera setup in a 2d game.

So it's finding the left side of the screen by following the right edge of the frustum *behind* the camera. Very odd. You can't follow the right side of the frustum to find where the left side of the screen if it's orthographic so it is no surprise that it doesn't work.

Instead, just use the left side of the frustum and make the depth positive by negating that component:

```
screenBounds = Camera.main.ViewportToWorldPoint(
        new Vector3(0f, 0f, -Camera.main.transform.position.z));
```